# Vertical diagram using ember

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been developing a diagram to display related items: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjardim/gs3w5/) using bootstrap 3.0. In the example I'm not using Ember. This it's a very simple example.

But the problem it's when I use Ember to generate the Items dynamically. The diagram doesn't is displayed as expeted on the first, last and only child selectors. This happens because the ember add one or two script tags before and after an element:

```
<div class="level closed" style="display: block;">
    <script id="metamorph-218-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-216-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <div class="item">
    <span class="title"><script id="metamorph-219-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Element name 1<script id="metamorph-219-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></span>
    </div>  
    <script id="metamorph-216-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-217-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <div class="item">
    <span class="title"><script id="metamorph-220-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Element name 2 <script id="metamorph-220-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></span>
    </div>  
    <script id="metamorph-217-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-218-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </div>
```

So for that I used:

```
.level >.item:nth-child(3):before {
    width: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.level >.item:nth-child(3):after {
    height: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.level > .item:nth-last-child(3):before {
    width: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.level >.item:nth-last-child(3):after {
    height: 10px;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

The problem is when I've only one child. Without ember I used the following css.

```
.item:only-child::after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc !important;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -7px !important;
    width: 48px;
    left: -48px;
}

.item:only-child::before {    
    width: 0px !important;
}
```

But as you can see because ember add this scripts tags there is no only-child and this css doesn't apply.

Comment: If you are generating these in code, then you should be able to give them class names dynamically, and use those class names instead of only-child or nth-child.  Oh, and that fiddle you posted looks pretty slick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to resolve that I've substitu the only-child selector in CSS for only-of-type

```
.item:only-of-type::after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc !important;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -7px !important;
    width: 48px;
    left: -48px;
}

.item:only-of-type::before {    
    width: 0px !important;
}
```

Thanks for your help and comments